# Save android key store when formatting mac

Tags: android, macos

i need to format and reinstall my macbook air.
my android keystore is located on my hardrive.
what is the best way to preserve it?
last time i tried putting it on a portable hard drive made it corrupted.
is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the *.keystore file wherever you want.  I  have both stored this in dropbox, and also mailed the file to myself (using GMail).  There is nothing OS specific about this file, and it can be saved anywhere without issue.

To be clear, you can store it on a portable hard-drive, so something else must have caused your previous issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mine has been on my Dropbox for years, and never had any issues. I switch between Mac OS X and Windows all the time.